# How to make the web page scrollabe when the browser size is reduced?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I am using HTML and CSS in my web application. I have defined all my attributes inside a table. When I change the size of my browser all the components are flushed together.

For example when I reduce the browser size on youtube a horizontal scroll bar appears which allows to navigate through the website but does not change anything on the home page. I want to implement something similar for my web app.

Inside the web page I a tried to put all the content inside a div and then use css style `overflow:sroll` for that. But it was no help.

I have an iframe inside my webpage.

```
<body>
    <table>
        <!--web content--> 
        <iframe></iframe>
    </table>
</body>
```

I cannot post my entire code as it's way to long. It's more than 1000 lines.

Comment: this task is automatically done browser when you reduce the page size.

Comment: read this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_frame_scrolling.asp

Comment: You should not use tables for layout, for this you have CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about whether the code `overflow:sroll` was a typo or not, you can just change `sroll` to `scroll` instead.

Also, maybe because of other CSS snippet defined the `overflow` attribute later on, you can try add this to your CSS code :

```
body {overflow:scroll!important;}
```

- First, `!important` is added to `overflow:scroll` to make it more important - than the later-defined `overflow` attribute.
- Second, you don't need to wrap it in a `<div>`, which is more convenient.

For other elements, just add `style="overflow:scroll;"` or `style="overflow:scroll!important;"` in case you really need to change the `overflow` attribute again.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tS9LS/)

Answer (score 0):

add "overflow-y:auto;" property into the css to perform scroll while resizing

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused with your question:

If you need a scroll bar in the iframe you could use `scrolling="yes"` like [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_scrolling):

If your question is about an internal scroll in your div, you must use the `overflow-x:scroll` and the `overflow-y:scroll`

If your question is about resizing browser behavior, you could use `@media screen`

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   //SOMETHING OF CSS HERE
}
/* Some android phone portrait screen width*/
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 360px) {
  //SOMETHING OF CSS HERE
}
```

I hope it helps you, SALUT!

Answer (score 0):

To implement scroll you must define height first, example if height is 200px, then if browser decrease its size more than 200px, only the overflow:scroll; will work, make sure you use border for demo purpose to table or div later try to use overflow, it should do a trick